# Removing rows having only zeros

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to remove all the rows having either zeros or NAs. In the code below I am selecting numeric variables and then filtering out 0s. Problem here is it does not return character variables along with numeric ones in the final output.

```
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = 
                   "x   y   z
a   1   2
b   0   3
c   1   NA
d 0 NA
")

df %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% filter(rowSums(., na.rm = T)!=0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter_if` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter_if(is.numeric, any_vars(. != 0 & !is.na(.)))

#  x y  z
#1 a 1  2
#2 b 0  3
#3 c 1 NA
```

Or using base R :

```
cols <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
df[rowSums(!is.na(df[cols]) & df[cols] != 0) > 0, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 filter(any(across(where(is.numeric)) != 0, na.rm = TRUE))

  x         y     z
  <fct> <int> <int>
1 a         1     2
2 b         0     3
3 c         1    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestions written in this new [doc page](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/colwise.html#how-do-you-convert-existing-code) after the release of `dplyr` version `1.0.0`, you can create a helper function to substitute the superseded functions `filter_if` and `any_vars`.

> Previously, `filter()` was paired with the `all_vars()` and `any_vars()`
> helpers. Now, `across()` is equivalent to `all_vars()`, and there’s no
> direct replacement for `any_vars()`. However you can make a simple
> helper yourself

From now on, this way should be the reference method for this kind of filtering steps.

```
rowAny <- function(x) {rowSums(x != 0 & !is.na(x)) > 0}
df %>% filter(rowAny(across(where(is.numeric))))

#   x y  z
# 1 a 1  2
# 2 b 0  3
# 3 c 1 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do

```
df[rowSums(suppressWarnings(sapply(df, as.double)), na.rm=TRUE) > 0, ]
#   x y  z
# 1 a 1  2
# 2 b 0  3
# 3 c 1 NA
```